# ListView exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, listview

I'm trying to create a program to run a specific application, which was selected in a ListView. I have a ListView named SoftView in my application and the code for DoubleClick event is the following:

```
private void SoftView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

 ...
 if (SoftView.Items[SoftView.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[0].Text == "Application name")

 {

  ...
   -- Run selected application --
  Application.Exit();

 }

}
```

On execution I have the following exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>
> Parameter name: index
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedIndexCollection.get_Item (Int32 index) [0x00000]
>
> at Launcher.MainForm.SoftView_DoubleClick (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListView+ItemControl.HandleClicks (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs me) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListView+ItemControl.ItemsMouseUp (System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs me) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListView+ItemControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000]
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the best way to implement sorting for a ListView. Have a look here for an example if you wish to change your sorting functionality. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

Answer (score 1):

There are no selected indexes at the moment when you double click

`SoftView.SelectedIndices` is empty. So `SoftView.SelectedIndices[0]` throws the exception.

The fix could be like this:

```
if (SoftView.Items.Count == 0)
    return;
if (SoftView.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    return;
if (SoftView.Items[SoftView.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[0].Text == "Application name")
    ...
```

Comment: No, I can not do this unfortunately :(

Comment: I have one guess, maybe this exception is because of termination of Application before event handler returns. I guess I should terminate the application and run the selected one after the DoubleClick handler returns.

Comment: @Max - hard to tell what is wrong without looking at the code. Technically I answered your question and explained why you had the exception. I guess you need to show more code and probably ask another question.